# c# custom class wanting to have a variable in place of the object name

Tags: c#, class, object, variables

'a local or parameter cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter' is the error I receive whenever I want to have a variable where the object name is for my custom class Book

it works fully with a non-variable name but whenever I make 'book1' a variable it comes up with the scope error

I want to make the 'book1' a variable so when the while loop loops over it create's a new object in the class. I have looked on the internet for over 2 hours and can't find a solution, I am new to programing so I might have been staring the solution in the face so I'm sorry if this is a common question asked and I'm sorry if I named things wrong and it made my explanation hard to read. thank you.

here is my code:

```
        string aTitle;
        string aAuthor;
        int aPages;
        int bookNo = 0;
        bool stop = false;
        string book1;

        while (!stop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started Creating Books, creating book:" + bookNo);
            Console.Write("Enter Books Title: ");
            aTitle = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Books Author: ");
            aAuthor = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Books Page Amount: ");
            aPages = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Book book1 = new Book(aTitle, aAuthor, aPages);
            
            Console.WriteLine(book1.title);
        }


class Book
{
    public string title;
    public string author;
    public int pages;
    public int bookNo;
    static public int NoOfBooks = 0;

    public Book(string aTitle, string aAuthor, int aPages)
    {
        title = aTitle;
        author = aAuthor;
        pages = aPages;
        NoOfBooks++;
        bookNo = NoOfBooks;

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Book {"+title+"} book number:"+bookNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn´t that obvious? You have a variable of type `string` in the outer scope and one of type `Book` in the loop, that both have the same name. You cannot have two variables of the same name within the same scope. Either rename the `Book`-variable in the loop or the string-variable outside the loop.

Comment: You gave you two variables the same name: `string book1` and `Book book1`. Your scope, in this case, is the class (that you did not posted). So everything between `string aTitle;` and your closing while-loop bracket. How should the compiler know, which `book1` you are refering too? Rename `string book1;` or remove it, since you do not use it anywhere.

Comment: sorry, you misunderstand. I am trying to stop book1 from being overwritten every time the loop loops. so I want to have book1 the label be changed to something like book2 or the title of the book instead of having just book1 being overwritten with new data. sorry if I didn't make this clear